# InAppPurchase Plugin in icenium

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova, icenium

Have anyone tried to use this plugin with Icenium?
Now Icenium is able to install any Plugman spec plugin to it.

I tried without success!

Comment: Could you provide a link to a repo, or post sample code here along with errors, and cordova version, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There is already an useful discussion including [a package](http://www.icenium.com/clientsfiles/a047dd02-0e5e-4497-9cf9-a780b9615ee3_InAppPurchaseManager.zip?sfvrsn=0) of the modified InAppPurchaseManager plugin ready to be imported and used in [Icenium forums here](http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/icenium-general-discussion/inapppurchase-plugin). How to import the plug-in and building the app with it:

- [Import Custom Plugins from Archive](http://docs.icenium.com/creating-your-project/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/add-custom-plugins)
- [Configure the Custom Plugin for Building Your App](http://docs.icenium.com/creating-your-project/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/configure-for-building)